# Logical flaw/s in my basic Python code to calculate sum of numbers?

Tags: python

I had to use 'try' and 'except' to calculate sum of numbers and account of invalid input. When user enters 'done', the program prints out result. What are he mistakes?

```py
total = 0
count = 0
while True :
    try :
      x = (input('enter an input \n'))
      y = float(x)
      print('your number is : ', y)
      count = count+1
      total = total + x
    except :
      if x == 'done':
          break
      else :
          print('invalid input')

print ('sum is' , total , 'and average is' , total/count)
```

Comment: what happens when you execute this code?

Comment: What happens if you run your code? Error messages? Edit the question to show it properly formatted.

Comment: The hint "try running the code" isn't useful because they're catching the error message and not printing it.  ;)

Comment: Thanks for editing code, I'm new to stackoverflow and next time I'll learn to post question properly. 

When I run the code it asks for number and when I enter an integer it seemingly executes both try and except blocks! This seems contradictory. This is what happened after entering number "10" :

your number is :  10.0
invalid input
enter an input

Comment: What if the call to `input` fails the first time?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing:

```
  x = (input('enter an input \n'))
  y = float(x)
  print('your number is : ', y)
  count = count+1
  total = total + x
```

i.e. attempting to add to `total` what was inputed by user as str, you should add float value, i.e.:

```
  x = (input('enter an input \n'))
  y = float(x)
  print('your number is : ', y)
  count = count+1
  total = total + y
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved it. I feel silly for this simple neglect.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing your `except` block so that it displays the error instead of "invalid input":

```
    except Exception as e:
      if x == 'done':
          break
      else:
          print(e)
```

This way it will tell the user what was wrong with the input -- and if anything else happens to go wrong in your code, it'll be easier to figure out!

Another option is to change your `except` to only catch `ValueError`s:

```
    except ValueError as e:
      if x == 'done':
          break
      else:
          print(e)
```

Any other kind of error (say, a `TypeError`) will then raise as normal.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your code is not correct. If the try is not successful, the `x` don't have value. You should check the "done" before the float casting. I have written a working version code.

**Code:**

```
total = 0
count = 0
while True:
    try:
        x = input("enter an input \n")
        if x == "done":
            break
        y = float(x)
        print("your number is : ", y)
        count += 1  # Use the '+=' for incrementation.
        total += y  # You should add the float type to total.
    except Exception:
        print("invalid input")

print("sum is", total, "and average is", total / count)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
enter an input 
1
your number is :  1.0
enter an input 
2
your number is :  2.0
enter an input 
test
invalid input
enter an input 
done
sum is 3.0 and average is 1.5
```